# pandas dataframe group with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, frequency

I have a 3D dataframe with x and y and time as 3rd dimension.
The data are 5 indizes of satellite images that were taken at different times.
The x and y describes every pixel.

```
 x        y              time       SIPI       classif
7.620001 -77.849990     2018-04-07  1.011107    2.0
                        2018-10-14  1.023407    2.0
                        2018-12-28  0.045107    3.0
                        2020-01-10  0.351107    2.0
                        2018-06-29  0.351107    2.0
         -77.849899     2018-04-07  1.010777    8.0
                        2018-10-14  0.510562    2.0
                        2018-12-28  1.410766    4.0
                        2020-01-10  1.010666    8.0
                        2018-06-29  2.057068    8.0
         -77.849809     2018-04-07  0.986991    1.0
                        2018-10-14  0.986991    8.0
                        2018-12-28  0.986991    5.0
                        2020-01-10  0.984791    5.0
                        2018-06-29  0.986991    3.0
         -77.849718     2018-04-07  0.975965    10.0
                        2018-10-14  0.964765    7.0
                        2018-12-28  0.975965    10.0
                        2020-01-10  0.975965    10.0
                        2018-06-29  0.975965    3.0
         -77.849627     2018-04-07  1.957747    2.0
                        2018-10-14  0.132445    6.0
                        2018-12-28  0.589677    2.0
                        2020-01-10  1.982445    2.0
                        2018-06-29  3.334456    7.0
```

I need to group the data and as new column I need the value from column 'classif_rf', which is most frequent in 5 datasets. The values are integers between 1 and 10. I want to add an condition which add only frequency higher than 3.

```
 x          y           classif
7.620001 -77.849990     2.0
         -77.849899     8.0
         -77.849809     Na
         -77.849718     10.0
         -77.849627     2.0
```

So as a result I need dataframe where each pixel has a value with highest frequency and when the frequency is lower than 3 there should be a NA value.

Can the pandas.groupby function do that? I thought about value_counts(), but I'm not sure how to implement that to my dataset.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: This is without the frequency greater than three condition: `df.groupby(["x", "y"])["classif"].agg(pd.Series.mode)`

Comment: I tried something like that, but how the function classify the value for a pixel, if  in a column 'classif' are 5 different values? Does the function take the first better value?

Comment: What do you mean "the first best value"? It takes the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)). Are you asking what it does in the event of a tie for the most frequent number in a group?

Comment: Sorry for incomprehensibility. I mean first-served value. I know that it takes the mode. Exactly, I was not sure, what the function does, if there are tie, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 7.

Comment: What do you want it to do? You haven't specified. In ,y answer, then `[0]` part means to just give you the first one it finds I think. If you want something more specific, like maybe the smallest mode you can change it to `pd.Series.mode(x).min()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a clunky way to do it:

```py
# Get the modes per group and count how often they occur
df_modes = df.groupby(["x", "y"]).agg(
    {
        'classif': [lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0], 
                    lambda x: sum(x == pd.Series.mode(x)[0])]
    }
).reset_index()
# Rename the columns to something a bit more readable
df_modes.columns = ["x", "y", "classif_mode", "classif_mode_freq"]
# Discard modes whose frequency was less than 3
df_modes.loc[df_modes["classif_mode_freq"] < 3, "classif_mode"] = np.nan
```

Now `df_modes.drop("classif_mode_freq", axis=1)` will return

```
          x          y  classif_mode
0  7.620001 -77.849990           2.0
1  7.620001 -77.849899           8.0
2  7.620001 -77.849809           NaN
3  7.620001 -77.849718          10.0
4  7.620001 -77.849627           2.0
```

Comment: Ist there a possible to make it without reset index? Because of that I loose the dimensions.  My actually dataframe looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A92v3.png and I need something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cPWA.png.

Now I tried this function:       count_cond = df.groupby(['x','y']).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])    , but I cannot apply there my condition.

Comment: I'm not sure - but you can always set lat and lon to be the index again after you're done